# How to convert an engineering project into a PhD research title?

Tags: phd

I am curious and also want to clear my understanding about the nature of research which students undertake in a PhD program.

Take [this product](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_XQotEmX0g) as an example.

1. What is the difference between the research behind the development of this product, and a PhD research which is able to earn a degree?
2. Does a 4-5 years' PhD research degree program allow developing a product like this?
3. Does the student need to mask his product development as a PhD thesis by selecting a cryptic title which sounds "wise", or would he be allowed to use a plain title like "A desktop sweater knitter"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the difference between the research behind the development of this product, and a PhD research which is able to earn a degree?

Products are typically *developed* from known results (including existing research), whereas *research* (during a PhD) produces new results.

> Does a 4-5 years' PhD research degree program allow developing a product like this?

Not typically: Research is time consuming and there typically isn't time to develop products.

> Does the student need to mask his product development as a PhD thesis by selecting a cryptic title which sounds "wise", or would he be allowed to use a plain title like "A desktop sweater knitter"?

I think you're (discretely) trying to ask: How can I develop a product during my PhD? *Don't do that*. If you do, the IP will (most) likely be owned by your university, not you. You'll need a less common approach: Work for a company (possibly your own) and enrol with a university under non-standard terms which ensure the company retains (all or most) IP rights.

Comment: "*Products are typically developed from known results (including existing research), whereas research (during a PhD) produces new results.*" --- kindly, elaborate.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want elaboration on. Nevertheless: Just look at a product, e.g., a pencil, there's nothing new there (it is just graphite wrapped in wood). By comparison, look at a research paper, it is by definition novel. Of course, I'm oversimplifying and generalising, but that's the core idea.